# How to detect floating numbers in a string and convert them into single intenger

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and I have a task to complete, but I could not find a way to do it so I'm asking you for help. This is my task: I have to take input from user, for example:

```
stackoverflow1.2312312321abcd42ds43
```

and append:
-  floating number into `floatList`
-  "42" into `evenList`
-  and 43 into `oddList`

This is what my code looks like atm:

```
user_input = input("Please enter the text: ")
```

#### Code:

```
freeText = ""
floatList = []
evenList = []
oddList = []

for i in user_input:
    if i.isdigit():
        i += freeText
    elif i != "":
        floatList.append(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Just a suggestion: adding the proper code formatting would greatly help the readability of your question and that should help with the quality of the answers.  Use triple back-ticks to wrap code blocks.

Comment: I have not yet learned that so I doubt it. In the code above I'm trying to convert multiple integers into whole number and after that I was going to find a way to detect floating number, but nothing worked.

Comment: How do you know a number is float ? How about even or odd? Then how do you add an item to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is:

- Go through the input character by character (as you did with `for i in ...`)
- While you are going through the input, build a string containing the number you have read so far (`current_number`).
- Also, have a boolean variable that states whether the number read so far contains a decimal dot (`has_decimal_dot`).
- If you encounter a digit, just append it to `current_number` and continue looking at the next character.
- If you encounter a dot, also append it to `current_number` and remember you encountered a dot. Then, continue looking at the next character.
- If finally you encounter a character that is not a digit nor a dot, you know the number you were reading has ended.

  - Then, if you encountered a dot, you know it was a float, so you convert the string to a float and append it to the floatlist.
  - If you didn't encounter a dot, `current_number` must be an integer, at least if it has a length > 0. Test modulo 2 to know whether it is even or odd.
  - After adding the number, you have to prepare for the next one. Set `current_number` again to an empty string, and `has_decimal_dot` to False
- A trick to not have to do something special for the last number in the string, make sure the string doesn't end with a digit. For example by appending a space.

```py
#user_input = input("Please enter the text: ")
user_input = "stackoverflow1.2312312321abcd42ds43"
   # in the beginning, it is easier to test if you don't have to type the input every time
   # when everything is working more or less, we can try with input from the user

floatList = []
evenList = []
oddList = []

user_input += " "  # add a non-digit at the end so we don't have to handle the last number differently

current_number = ""
has_decimal_dot = False
for i in user_input:
    if i.isdigit():
        current_number += i  # append the character to the string
    elif i == ".":
        current_number += i
        has_decimal_dot = True
    else: # not a digit and not a dot
        if has_decimal_dot and len(current_number) > 1: # the nunber has a dot, but is not only a dot
            floatList.append(float(current_number))
        elif len(current_number) > 0:  # we encountered a non-digit, and the number we were building is not empty
            num = int(current_number)
            if num % 2 == 0:
                evenList.append(num)
            else:
                oddList.append(num)
        current_number = ""  # we just handled the number, now prepare for a next one
        has_decimal_dot = False
```